# syntax help need for arm template "id"

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am attempting to the below line from resource explorer for a deployment of a Load balancer
/subscriptions/7450e323-8ffc-461f-9b0a-e035f26b/resourceGroups/app-testdev-network-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/app-vnet-001/subnets/app501-iam-dev-sql-subnet01

and make it a little more useful by using some parameters

```
"[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('vnetname'),'/subnets/',parameters('subnetName'))]"
```

vnetname = app-vnet-001 and subnetname = app501-iam-dev-sql-subnet01 - however, when I try to deploy the arm template I get the following output from Visual Studio - do I need to add the concat function here?  I have used resourceID before but nothing this complex to date.

> Template deployment returned the following errors: 13:54:45 - 1:54:38
>   PM - Resource Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers
>   'app501-iam-dev-sql-lb01' failed with message '{ 13:54:45 -   "error":
>   { 13:54:45 -     "code": "InvalidTemplate", 13:54:45 -     "message":
>   "Unable to process template language expressions for resource
>   '/subscriptions/7450e323--461f-9b0a-cdc0e035f26b/resourceGroups/app501-iam-dev-sql-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/app501-iam-dev-sql-lb01' at line '48' and column '9'. 'Unable to evaluate template language
>   function 'resourceId': function requires exactly one multi-segmented
>   argument which must be resource type including resource provider
>   namespace. Current function arguments
>   'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/,app-vnet-001,/subnets/,app501-iam-dev-sql-subnet01'.
>   Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#resourceid for
>   usage details.'" 13:54:45 -   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should specify resource type as a single string in `resourceId()` function.

```
"[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('vnetname'),parameters('subnetName'))]"
```

reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#resourceid

Comment: Thanks for the input - got it to work...the link really helped and I think will help in the future.  For anyone else or to make it perhaps a little clearer...I did this  added this variable "variables": {
    "vnetref": "[resourceId(parameters('virtualNetworkRG'),'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('vnetname'))]" and then modified the above to use the new defined variable and adding the concat function "subnet": {
                "id": "[concat(variables('vnetref'),'/subnets/',parameters('subnetName'))]"